# Making clickable rows with jQuery and excluding child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with rows that I would like to be clickable, however there is also a button in one of my columns which when pressed should do an alternative actions.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr data-url="link.html">
        <td>Some Text Value <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="otherFunction()"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-url="link2.html">
        <td>Some Text Value <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="otherFunction()"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-url="link3.html">
        <td>Some Text Value <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="otherFunction()"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table tr:not(input)').click(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr("data-url");
        if(href) {
            //console.log('redirect to:' + href);
            window.location = href;
        }
    });
});
```

Currently when I click on the button the page is still redirect despite the jQuery selector excluding any inputs. Am I using the `:not` incorrectly?

Comment: Can you share code of `otherFunction();` as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check in the click handler whether the button was clicked by checking the `event.target` property

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table tr').click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is(':button')) {
      snippet.log('button clicked')
      return;
    }

    snippet.log('row clicked');
    var href = $(this).attr("data-url");
    if (href) {
      //console.log('redirect to:' + href);
      window.location = href;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr data-url="link.html">
    <td>Some Text Value
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="otherFunction()">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-url="link2.html">
    <td>Some Text Value
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="otherFunction()">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-url="link3.html">
    <td>Some Text Value
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="otherFunction()">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to ckeck the `target` of the `event`passed to the `click` function.

Here is a working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".clickablerow").click(function(event) {
    if(event.target.tagName != "INPUT"){
      var href = $(this).attr("data-url");
      if(href) {
        //console.log('redirect to:' + href);
        window.location = href;
      }
    }
  });
});

function otherFunction() {
  alert("other function");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="clickablerow" data-url="link.html">
        <td>Some Text Value <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="otherFunction()"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickablerow" data-url="link2.html">
        <td>Some Text Value <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="otherFunction()"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickablerow" data-url="link3.html">
        <td>Some Text Value <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="otherFunction()"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```